# How to use method swizzling to change the system font used in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, xib, uifont, method-swizzling

I am creating an iOS app in which different fonts must be used for different languages.

I am trying to do this by using `systemFont` everywhere in the app and at runtime, changing what `systemFont` refers to depending on the language.

Following is the code used to swizzle the class methods of `UIFont`-

```swift
extension UIFont {
    static let setSystemFont: Void = {
        let m1 = class_getClassMethod(UIFont.self, #selector(systemFont(ofSize:)))!
        let m2 = class_getClassMethod(UIFont.self, #selector(customFont(ofSize:)))!
        method_exchangeImplementations(m1, m2)

        let m3 = class_getClassMethod(UIFont.self, #selector(preferredFont(forTextStyle:)))!
        let m4 = class_getClassMethod(UIFont.self, #selector(customFont(forTextStyle:)))!
        method_exchangeImplementations(m3, m4)

        let m5 = class_getClassMethod(UIFont.self, #selector(boldSystemFont(ofSize:)))!
        let m6 = class_getClassMethod(UIFont.self, #selector(boldCustomFont(ofSize:)))!
        method_exchangeImplementations(m5, m6)

        let m7 = class_getClassMethod(UIFont.self, #selector(italicSystemFont(ofSize:)))!
        let m8 = class_getClassMethod(UIFont.self, #selector(italicCustomFont(ofSize:)))!
        method_exchangeImplementations(m7, m8)

        let m9 = class_getClassMethod(UIFont.self, #selector(systemFont(ofSize:weight:)))!
        let m10 = class_getClassMethod(UIFont.self, #selector(customFont(ofSize:weight:)))!
        method_exchangeImplementations(m9, m10)

        let m11 = class_getClassMethod(UIFont.self, #selector(preferredFont(forTextStyle:compatibleWith:)))!
        let m12 = class_getClassMethod(UIFont.self, #selector(customFont(forTextStyle:compatibleWith:)))!
        method_exchangeImplementations(m11, m12)
    }()
}

private extension UIFont {
    @objc
    class func customFont(ofSize fontSize: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: fontSize)!
    }
    @objc
    class func customFont(forTextStyle style: UIFont.TextStyle) -> UIFont {
        UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 15)!
    }
    @objc
    class func boldCustomFont(ofSize fontSize: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: fontSize)!
    }
    @objc
    class func italicCustomFont(ofSize fontSize: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: fontSize)!
    }
    @objc
    class func customFont(ofSize fontSize: CGFloat, weight: UIFont.Weight) -> UIFont {
        UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: fontSize)!
    }
    @objc
    class func customFont(forTextStyle style: UIFont.TextStyle, compatibleWith traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIFont {
        UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 15)!
    }
}
```

Note- `Chalkduster` is used so that font change is easily observed.

In `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)`, the following code is called

```swift
UIFont.setSystemFont
```

When the app is run, I observe that for any programmatically created views, the `systemFont` is changed and the `Chalkduster` font is used.

However, for any views instantiated from xib files, the system font is not changed.

Can anyone point out how to change the system font used in the xib files without changing the font in the xib file?

Comment: Seems like you're doing some overengineering. I'm not sure you should even resort to method swizzling here